# Get item in the list in Scala?

Tags: scala

How in the world do you get just an element at index **i** from the List in scala?

I tried `get(i)`, and  `[i]` - nothing works. Googling only returns how to "find" an element in the list. But I already know the index of the element!

Here is the code that does not compile:

```
def buildTree(data: List[Data2D]):Node ={
  if(data.length == 1){
      var point:Data2D = data[0]  //Nope - does not work
       
  }
  return null
}
```

Looking at the [List api](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) does not help, as my eyes just cross.

Comment: Well well, it seems like **data.head** worked... But still that only gives me first element, not any one in the list.

Comment: Use the **Seq** traits **apply(index)** if you are sure the index is not out of bounds. _http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?_ga=1.201071334.935145902.1460491527#scala.collection.Seq_

Comment: data.drop(i).head works for accessing i-th element

Comment: @Vinay That is a costly operation. So one should avoid "drop(i).head".

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
data(2)
```

But you don't really want to do that with lists very often, since linked lists take time to traverse.  If you want to index into a collection, use `Vector` (immutable) or `ArrayBuffer` (mutable) or possibly `Array` (which is just a Java array, except again you index into it with `(i)` instead of `[i]`).

Comment: Basically I'm looking for something like ArrayList in java. I guess immutable would be fine too.

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` works like `ArrayList`.  `Vector` works like an immutable `ArrayList`--you can read, but you can't write without creating a new one.

Comment: How about a subList? For example in java I do "data.subList(0, index)".

Comment: Nevermind, I got it - it's "slice"! Can I convert ArrayBuffer to Vector? Or is there a more generic type I can return from methods? For example in Java I would return List interface.

Comment: You can convert `ArrayBuffer` to an `IndexedSeq` using `.toIndexedSeq`; `IndexedSeq` is the more generic type.  (In this case it actually turns out to be implemented as a `Vector`.)  `IndexedSeq` is the supertype of collections that are reasonable to index into.  Also, note that you could do `Vector() ++ myArrayBuffer`, which will work for almost any collection (on either side).  `++` builds a new collection from the two you specify, preserving the type of the one on the left.  `Vector()` is the empty vector, so it would produce what you want.

Comment: Only do this if you are totally sure that data has an element at index `2`. Even if you are fairly sure, you should probably use `data.lift(2)` (see my answer) so the out of bounds exception is type-checked.

Comment: @adamnfish - It's worth noting that the current implementation of `lift(n)` throws an exception when out of bounds; `tail(n).headOption` is more efficient if you actually are likely to try to retrieve an index that's out of range.

Answer (score 153):

Safer is to use `lift` so you can extract the value if it exists and fail gracefully if it does not.

```
data.lift(2)
```

This will return None if the list isn't long enough to provide that element, and Some(value) if it is.

```
scala> val l = List("a", "b", "c")
scala> l.lift(1)
Some("b")
scala> l.lift(5)
None
```

Whenever you're performing an operation that may fail in this way it's great to use an Option and get the type system to help make sure you are handling the case where the element doesn't exist.

**Explanation:**

This works because List's `apply` (which sugars to just parentheses, e.g. `l(index)`) is like a partial function that is defined wherever the list has an element. The `List.lift` method turns the partial `apply` function (a function that is only defined for some inputs) into a normal function (defined for any input) by basically wrapping the result in an Option.

Comment: Lift is beautiful. I can avoid arrayIndexOutOfBound errors, without checking size of array..

Comment: The opposite of a "partial" function (only defined for some input, not all) is a "total" function (defined for all input). What you call a "normal" function is technically called a "total" function. The inferred `apply` as in `l(1)` [which is really just shorthand for `l.apply(1)`] in your example is a partial function. The function `l.lift(1)` is a total function. Wrapping any partial function in an `Option` (or `Try` or `Either`) makes it a total function.

Answer (score 11):

Why parentheses?

Here is the quote from the book [programming in scala](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/next-steps-in-scala.html).

> Another important idea illustrated by this example will give you insight into why arrays are accessed with parentheses in Scala. Scala has fewer special cases than Java. Arrays are simply instances of classes like any other class in Scala. When you apply parentheses surrounding one or more values to a variable, Scala will transform the code into an invocation of a method named apply on that variable. So greetStrings(i) gets transformed into greetStrings.apply(i). Thus accessing an element of an array in Scala is simply a method call like any other. This principle is not restricted to arrays: any application of an object to some arguments in parentheses will be transformed to an apply method call. Of course this will compile only if that type of object actually defines an apply method. So it's not a special case; it's a general rule.

Here are a few examples how to pull certain element (first elem in this case) using functional programming style.

```
  // Create a multdimension Array 
  scala> val a = Array.ofDim[String](2, 3)
  a: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null, null), Array(null, null, null))
  scala> a(0) = Array("1","2","3")
  scala> a(1) = Array("4", "5", "6")
  scala> a
  Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
```

---

```
  // 1. paratheses
  scala> a.map(_(0))
  Array[String] = Array(1, 4)
  // 2. apply
  scala> a.map(_.apply(0))
  Array[String] = Array(1, 4)
  // 3. function literal
  scala> a.map(a => a(0))
  Array[String] = Array(1, 4)
  // 4. lift
  scala> a.map(_.lift(0))
  Array[Option[String]] = Array(Some(1), Some(4))
  // 5. head or last 
  scala> a.map(_.head)
  Array[String] = Array(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use parentheses `()` to access the list of elements, as shown below.

```
list_name(index)
```